# Ref 'is posibly null' and 'Property does not exist on type 'never'.' in Vue script Setup

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to access a child component `ref` in a component in Vue, inside on `onMounted` hook and I'm getting this error:

> 'myRef is posibly null'

```
<template>
  <MyChildComponent ref="myRef"></MyChildComponent>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const myRef = ref(null)

onMounted(() =>{
  //Error(just on the IDE): 'myRef is posibly null'
  console.log(myRef.value.someProp.someProp)//Child properties are exposed on the child component
})

</script>
```

I saw on some posts that using `?.` can solve the problem, but then I get another error warning:

> 'Property does not exist on type 'never'

```
onMounted(() =>{
  //Error(just on the IDE): 'Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'never'
  console.log(myRef?.value?.someProp.someProp)
                          //----------------//
})
```

The error only show in Vscode, but not in the browser, it justs log the property, but I'm afraid that the warnings are there for a good reason.

I've tryed to type my ref but still not working: `const myRef<MyChildComponent> = ref()` and const `myRef<typeof MyChildComponent> = ref()` with no luck.

How can I solve this: how can I acces the right way to a child component or how can I supress the vscode warning? ?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed you have not typed the ref in any way. That means TypeScript will assume it's `never` and will always basically be null without any properties.

If you want to type it you need to type the ref itself:

```
const myRef = ref<MyChildComponent | null>(null);
```

This way the type is correctly known. Of course you still have to check if it is null before using it. Due to the way the component refs work you can't type it as never being null.

So either you use `myRef.value?.someProp` if you want to allow the end result being null, or you just `if` it not being null first.

Note that `myRef` can never be null. It's the ref itself and it always has a value. So you don't need null coalescing between `myRef` and its `value` property.

Also the reason why there is no warning/error in the browser is because the browser knows nothing of TypeScript. It only knows JavaScript and will not check for any type information beforehand.

Comment: Thaks for the response. I've tryed to type my ref but I get an error: `MyChildComponent refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyChildCOmponent?` So I use <typeof MyChildComponent | null> but still showing me the `does not exist on type 'never'`